# Are there any currently supported alternatives to DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I was working on an Android app and was wondering if there were any currently supported first party alternatives to DrawerLayout. Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what other kind of design you had in mind

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm pretty sure there are no other first party views that are designed specifically to give you the drawer like effect (that are not deprecated, i.e. the old slide drawer).

Even the brand new navigation view is meant to be combined in a drawer layout.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

I can only speculate as to why you are asking, but I'd guess it's because the DrawerLayout is in the v4 support package.  Support packages aren't just repositories for replacement parts for old APIs, a lot android newer/optional features end up in a support package as well.

The only alternative I can think of (using built-in views) is to roll your own using a fragment, but that would be pretty advanced indeed.